# Background image isn’t showing at div class in ionic

Tags: background-image, ionic-framework

I am working on android project with ionic framework.
I have www\templates\home.html in which I am using images for item icon.

my view code home.html

```
<ion-content>
<div class="row gray">
 <div class="col"><div class="abc"></div>
 Opening Balance</div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

my css in style.css:

```
.abc{
 background: url('../img/icon.png');
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you running it in a browser (better than a simulator for debugging)? Check the error console and you should be able to find more information out

Comment: yes, i am running in a google chrome.

Comment: any errors the js console?

Comment: yes, i got GET http://localhost/www/img/icon.png 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make sure the file path is correct
2. make sure the permissions on the file are allowed. If you copied the image from somewhere, the permissions may not allow you to use it on your project.

Comment: finally, this solved. stupid of me.
Thanks for your help

Comment: no problem, glad it worked out. I just started on ionic today... good luck to us!:P

Comment: yeah good luck to ,I thought it was not allowed to use ionic own icon. but it's wrong :D